# Способ хранения в базе

Tags: mysql

Нужно хранить в базе записи о названии иностранного языка и уровне его владения, к примеру:

```
English - Beginer
English -Intermediate
German - Beginer
```

Так же у одной записи может быть одновременно

```
English - Intermediate и German - Beginer
```

По сути можно сделать через id_language_level и хранить все в другой базе:

```
CREATE TABLE `ge_language_level` (
    `id_language_level` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `language` VARCHAR(150) NULL DEFAULT '',
    `level` VARCHAR(150) NULL DEFAULT '',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id_language_level`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
;
```

Ну как быть в таком случаи если нужно хранить одновременно запись о двух и больше языках?
Основная таблица:

```
CREATE TABLE `ge_project` (
    `id_project` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `position` VARCHAR(350) NOT NULL,
    `company` VARCHAR(350) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `city` VARCHAR(150) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `prog_language` VARCHAR(350) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `id_language_level` VARCHAR(350) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `phone` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `email` VARCHAR(100) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `salary` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `short_description` VARCHAR(400) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `content` TEXT NOT NULL,
    `id_employee` TINYINT(4) NOT NULL,
    `active` TINYINT(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
    `actuality` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT '9999-99-99',
    `date_add` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id_project`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=12
;


 INSERT INTO `ge_project` (`position`, `company`, `city`, `prog_language`, 
`phone`, `email`, `salary`, `short_description`, `content`, `id_employee`, 
`actuality`, `date_add`) VALUES ('Frontend Java Developer', 'eqw', 'Киев', 
'JavaScript', '', '', '', 'Ищем сильного фронтовика в комманду', '312', '3', 
'2018-02-15', '2018-02-01 10:57:14');
```

Натолкните на правильное решение, битый час сижу над этим.

Comment: Уровень языка должен быть у кого-то, а не в вакууме. Значит вам нужна классическая 1:М табличка `кто-то`, `язык`, `уровень владения`. `Кто-то` и `язык` являются составным первичным ключом.

Comment: Отношение (Проект, Язык, Уровень) приведите к 2НФ. Изучите Нормальные формы БД, поймете как строить другие отношения.